# Venn of \$n\$ statements

Tags: code-golf, binary-matrix, set-theory, open-ended-function

Given a positive integer \$n\$, output \$n\$ 2D bool images with the same width and height such that:

1. Each image should be 4-connected, i.e. for each two pixels that are true, you can start from one and go up, down, left and right for some times to the other pixel, only passing through true pixels.
2. Each image should have no holes, i.e. the complement should be 4-connected.
3. If we choose itself or its complement for each image, their intersection should be non-empty and 4-connected.

### Examples (only a finite amount of solutions shown, but there are infinitely many more)

Input: 1

Possible output:

```
.....
.***.
.**..
..*..
```

Input: 1

Possible output:

```
.....
...*.
.....
.....
```

Input: 2

Possible output:

```
..... .....
.***. ..**.
..... ..**.
..... .....
```

Input: 2

Possible output:

```
..... .....
.**.. ..**.
..**. ..**.
..... .....
```

Input: 3

Possible output:

```
..... ..... .....
.**.. ..**. .....
.**.. ..**. .***.
..... ..... .***.
```

Input: 4

Possible output:

```
....... ....... ....... .......
.***... ..***.. ....... .......
.***... ..***.. .*****. .......
.***... ..***.. .*****. .*****.
.***... ..***.. ....... .*****.
....... ....... ....... .......
```

The shortest code in each language wins.

[Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram#Extensions_to_higher_numbers_of_sets)

[Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17453/)

Comment: can output be binary matrices?

Comment: @Wasif That's quite reasonable

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Fixed. Not sure what happened to my thought that time making a wrong n=4 example.

Comment: Do the images have to be distinct?  What should be output if `n` is too large (do I have to ensure that the image size is large enough to accommodate all n)?

Comment: @Spitemaster Condition 3 already implies that the images must be distinct (if \$A = B\$, then \$A ∩ \bar B ∩ C ∩ D = \varnothing\$), and also that you must choose the width and height to be large enough for the given \$n\$.

Comment: I'm trying to understand rule 3.  Does it mean: "Pick any two of your outputted images, possibly complementing either one of them.  Now, the intersection equals the pixels that are TRUE for both.  There should be a non-zero number of these pixels, and they should be 4-connected".

Comment: @DominicvanEssen If you take the entire set of all images, then all \$2^N\$ arrangements of taking the image or its complement for each should be valid. As an example, if you have A, B, C, then the intersections of ABC, AB(!C), A(!B)C, A(!B)(!C), (!A)BC, (!A)B(!C), (!A)(!B)C, and (!A)(!B)(!C) all need to be valid.

Answer (score 8):

## Python, 62 bytes

```python
lambda n:[[[0,j>>i&1,1]for j in range(1<<n)]for i in range(n)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjo62kAny84uU81QxzA2Lb9IIUshM0@hKDEvPVXD0MYmTxMsmIkQBIr8TyvKz1UoKCjKzCtRyMwtyC8qgfK4IJRGmoaJpuZ/AA)

Generates \$3 × 2^n\$ images like these:

```python
..*  ..*  ..*  ..*
.**  ..*  ..*  ..*
..*  .**  ..*  ..*
.**  .**  ..*  ..*
..*  ..*  .**  ..*
.**  ..*  .**  ..*
..*  .**  .**  ..*
.**  .**  .**  ..*
..*  ..*  ..*  .**
.**  ..*  ..*  .**
..*  .**  ..*  .**
.**  .**  ..*  .**
..*  ..*  .**  .**
.**  ..*  .**  .**
..*  .**  .**  .**
.**  .**  .**  .**
```

Comment: @xnor I guess it wasn’t clear whether “complement” includes the outside of the image rectangle. I added the empty column to be safe.

Comment: the question says`bool images with same width and height`, are 3x2^n images allowed?

Comment: @Razetime The question means that the widths of the \$n\$ images are the same and the heights of the \$n\$ images are the same, not that the width equals the height. See the question’s examples.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>12</s> <s>10</s> <s>9</s> <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
4,6Bṗz
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/99Ex8zp4c7pVf8Pt0c9alrzcHf3o8Z9ynqRQHYWkHVo26Ft//@bAQA)

Returns a list of binary matrices (that is, a 3D list).

Output for \$n=6\$, transposed and ASCII-artified:

```
################################################################
................................################################
................................................................

################################################################
................################................################
................................................................

################################################################
........########........########........########........########
................................................................

################################################################
....####....####....####....####....####....####....####....####
................................................................

################################################################
..##..##..##..##..##..##..##..##..##..##..##..##..##..##..##..##
................................................................

################################################################
.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#.#
................................................................
```

### Explanation

```
4,6Bṗz Main monadic link, taking n as the argument
4,6    [4,6]
   B   Convert to binary: [[1,0,0],[1,1,0]]
    ṗ  Cartesian power to n
     z Zip with filler n (since it's already a rectangle, the filler will be ignored)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 64 bytes

```r
function(n)Map(function(i)rbind(1,(1:(2^n)-1)%/%2^i%%2,0),1:n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/pflpqXl2f7P600L7kkMz9PI0/TN7FAA87N1CxKysxL0TDU0TC00jCKy9PUNdRU1Vc1istUVTXSMdDUMbTKAwpBzNEw1OSCMIxgDGPN/wA)

Port of [Anders Kaseorg's approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/230107/95126) - upvote that one!

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
46SbIãIζ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/fxCw4yfPwYs9z2/7/NwMA)

Comment: You can remove the second `I` (or just use `ø` instead of `Iζ`).